# Encoding and Passing JSON Object from multiple input values on Create method in Laravel 5.1 Controller

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, view, controller

I have articles controller and view for filling a create a `form` in Laravel.

In creating the `form` I have an article, which is the base for mandatory data such as topic and description, and parts, which are optional fields. Parts are spawned by a `javascript` code and they contain only optional fields.

At the moment input field types are set to multiple, so in `controller` they return values such as

```
"sub_header":["optional 1","optional 2"],
"text_field":["optional 1","optional 2"]
```

These values are `arrays`, but I want to nest them inside an `Array` as `JSON-objects` for making controller logic easier to understand.

I didn't find a way to nest many input fields inside a `JSON-object` in submit. I know this can be done as an `Ajax` call, but I would prefer submitting the form only once.

So the aim is passing data from view to controller in format something like this :

```
{
"topic":"Test Topic", "description":"Give a short description of the 
Article.",
"media_description":"Give a short description of media element.",
  "parts":[
    "part-1":{
    "sub_header":"optional 1",
    "text_field":"optional 1"
    },
    "part-2":{
    "sub_header":"optional 2",
    "text_field":"optional 2"
    }
  ],
"published":"1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

Wasn't so hard after all.... Seems like this was more HTML / Javascript than Laravel / Blade problem. Sorry for misleading keywords.

So all I changed was the input.name when spawning inputs in JavaScript to :

input.name = "parts[part-" + taskRunningNumber + "][sub_header]";

and everything turned out for fine.

Now the value passed to controller is following :

```
{
"topic":"mandatory 1",
"description":"mandatory 1",
"media_description":"mandatory 1",
"parts":{
  "part-1":{
    "sub_header":"optional 1",
    "text_field":"optional 1",
    "media":null
    },
  "part-2":{
    "sub_header":"optional 2",
    "text_field":"optional 2",
    "media":null
    }
  },
"published":"1"
}
```

Even though tasks is not an array I think I can manage with that.